# Export image collecton with name using Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, code-review

I am using GEE for a new collection of images and I need to export it by automating the name of each image, for example, that month one is called January, and so on, how can I do it?

My code is here:

```
///12 images, one for each month for all years
//Define months

var months = ee.List.sequence(1, 12);

//Get one image for each month from the average of all of them in a single month.
//These images are from the collection with Snow and Cloud bands.

var monthly = months.map(function(m) {
  var filtered = CollectionSnowandCloud.filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange({
    start: m,
    field: 'month'
  }));
  return filtered.mean()
      .set('month', m);
});

//Create collection with 12 images, one for each month with the two bands

var NewCollection_monthly_12 = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(monthly)
print('Collection with 12 images:', NewCollection_monthly_12);


var list = NewCollection_monthly_12.toList(12);
for(var i=0;i<12;i++){
  // make a client-side name for export
  var nam = ee.String('Month')
             .cat(ee.String(ee.Number(i)))
             .getInfo();

  // get the image from the collection.toList()
  var imgExport = ee.Image(list.get(i))

  Export.image.toDrive({   
         image: imgExport,
         description: nam,
         scale:30,
         maxPixels:1e9
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can hard code your months in a list,

```
var monthList = ee.List(["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
  "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"
]);
```

then get them via the indices of your loop

```
for(var i=0;i<12;i++){
  // make a client-side name for export
  var nam = ee.String(monthList.get(i)) // using the loop index to get the corresponding month string
            .getInfo();
  // get the image from the collection.toList()
  var imgExport = ee.Image(list.get(i))

  Export.image.toDrive({   
         image: imgExport,
         description: nam,
         scale:30,
         maxPixels:1e9
  });
}
```

Comment: this really solved my problem, I thank you very much for it.

Comment: Glad that helps, cheers!